# Is it possible for Lie algebras over $\mathbb{Z}$ to have multiple associated root systems?

Tags: field-theory, lie-algebras

There is a well known bijection between simple Lie algebras over an algebraically closed field and root systems. Now if $\mathfrak{g}$ is a simple Lie algebra over a not algebraically closed field $K$ there is still some root system lurking behind the scenes: it is the root system $R$ associated to $\overline{\mathfrak{g}} := \mathfrak{g} \otimes_K \overline{K}$ where $\overline{K}$ is an algebraic closure of $K$ and $\overline{\mathfrak{g}}$ is 'reinterpreted' as an algebra over $\overline{K}$. People sometimes say that $\mathfrak{g}$ is 'of type $R$'. E.g. the non-isomorphic Lie algbras $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ and $\mathfrak{sl}(n, \mathbb{R})$ over $K = \mathbb{R}$ are both of type $A_{n-1}$.

So far so good. Now if I have a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ defined over $\mathbb{Z}$, I can still do more or less do the same thing and look at $\overline{\mathfrak{g}} := \mathfrak{g} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \overline{K}$ where $\overline{K}$ is just any algebraically closed field and get a root system attached to it.

However, my choices of $\overline{K}$ can be vastly different: it could be $\mathbb{C}$ but also the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_2$ or something similar but slightly less horrific, like the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ for $p > 3$. Is there any guarantee that the resulting root systems will still be the same? (In other words: does it makes sense to talk about what type $\mathfrak{g}$ is without specifying the field?)

Comment: That "well known" bijection, AFAIK, holds only for algebraically closed fields *of characteristic $0$*. Even ignoring that, if you allow positive characteristic here, of course you can just look at something like $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb Z) \oplus \mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb F_{17})$ which, when tensored with any algebraically closed field of characteristic $\neq 17$, will give something with root system $A_1$, but when tensored with $\mathbb F_{17}$ or its algebraic closure will have a root system of type $A_1 \times A_2$. Please clarify if such mixes of characteristic are meant to be allowed.

Comment: Aaah this is brilliant. I was not aware of the correspondence with root system working only in characteristic zero! This changes everything... Do you know what the classification of Lie algebras over algebraically closed fields of positive characteristic looks like? (@TorstenSchoeneberg)

Comment: As far as I know, that is a tough question and still unclear for small primes $p$. Cf. https://www.degruyter.com/serial/STRADE%20GEM%202A-B/html (abstract here https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/strade/fly.pdf), and this MO post by Jim Humphreys from 2010: https://mathoverflow.net/a/46822/27465. @DietrichBurde knows much more, I think. Maybe you want to write that as separate question, I'd like to see that answered myself.